# What would this SQL query do?

Tags: sql

I just came across this SQL Query in this [article](http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#select)

What does this SQL Query actually do when executed ?

Query:

```
SELECT 'ID' COL, MAX(ID) AS MAX 
FROM TEST 
UNION 
SELECT 'NAME', MAX(NAME) 
FROM TEST;
```

Comment: you have query and data so you will test it ... why ask ?

Comment: What is the exact question? maybe what is the result? or what SQL server doing during the execution? or somthing else

Comment: If you know the logical meaning of union you will probably understand this query without any knowledge of sql.

Comment: I am clear with the working of  UNION . What confuses me is the statement before UNION. How is the SQL server doing when the part before the UNION is executed?

Comment: The two legs in the union are supposed to be of the same type (union compatible). Judging by the names I would guess that `MAX(ID)` and `MAX(NAME)` have different types. Some DBMS will throw an error, some will cast one to the other, so it depends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query creates a column called COL and puts literal value of 'ID' in it.

It then provides the first (or highest) ID (numeric or alphabetic depending on what type of field ID is) and places it in the same row as the literal value "ID" under the column named (MAX).

It then takes the first (or highest) NAME depending on field type also, and puts the literal value "Name" into the COL column and the first/highest name into the second column (MAX).

The UNION combines those two rows into a single result set.